# How do you set the terminal output's width to 80 columns in MariaDB?

Tags: terminal, mariadb, output

I am **not** referring to *database columns*, I am referring to **Terminal Columns**.
How do you ask MariaDB to format its output for a standard 80 columns terminal ? Right now it outputs in however many columns fit the output so I basically have to fullscreen the terminal which is inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume with "MariaDB" you mean the command line client.

The simple answer is: you can't.

If your results are hard to read, try vertical output, instead of `;` as a delimiter of a SQL statement use `\G` or start command line client with option `-E`.

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from information_schema.columns limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           TABLE_CATALOG: def
            TABLE_SCHEMA: tmp
              TABLE_NAME: bulk_null
             COLUMN_NAME: a
        ORDINAL_POSITION: 1
          COLUMN_DEFAULT: NULL
             IS_NULLABLE: NO
               DATA_TYPE: int
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: NULL
  CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH: NULL
       NUMERIC_PRECISION: 10
           NUMERIC_SCALE: 0
      DATETIME_PRECISION: NULL
      CHARACTER_SET_NAME: NULL
          COLLATION_NAME: NULL
             COLUMN_TYPE: int(11)
              COLUMN_KEY: PRI
                   EXTRA: auto_increment
              PRIVILEGES: select,insert,update,references
          COLUMN_COMMENT: 
            IS_GENERATED: NEVER
   GENERATION_EXPRESSION: NULL
```

Comment: It’s a shame they can’t just split the horizontal table across multiple “lines” instead. Thank you.

Comment: It is not a shame.If you think it would be an important feature, file an issue in MariaDB's bug tracker or write and contribute this feature your self. That's how Open Source works.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate the output:

```
MariaDB [myDB]>pager cut -c -80
```

but I use

```
MariaDB [myDB]> pager cut -c -$COLUMNS
```

...which sets it to whatever my terminal happens to be at the time.

then

```
 MariaDB [myDB]>pager
```

to go back to stdout / full data wrapped

(you can also set it in `~/.my.cnf` apparently)

This is on linux (Alma linux 8.8 / RHEL 8.8 , KDE/Konsole but should work on linux generally). If on windows you can likely get a windows version of `cut` set up - it may be one of the programs installed along with git or may be doable with [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs?activeTab=readme) (dunno if `cut` is in there) or you could do a batch program to do it "a windows way".

credit to [John Willis](http://www.johnwillis.com/2014/10/mysql-format-output-to-no-wrap.html) where I found this originally.